# Podio Javascript WebForm

Tags: javascript, webforms, podio

I'm trying to pass variable to Podio Webform. It works on there sharable form link but not the Javascript form. This is what I have so far.

```
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->
<script src="https://podio.com/webforms/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _podioWebForm.render("xxxxxx")
</script>

<noscript>
  <a href="https://podio.com/webforms/xxxxxx/xxxxxx?&fields[forename]=<?php echo $Firstname;?>&fields[surname]=<?php echo$Surname;?>&fields[email][][value]=<?php echo '$Email';?>&fields[source]=01_h_vr&fields[extra]=<?php echo $Email.', '.$Firstname.', '.$Surname; ?>&fields[ip]=<?php echo $Ip;?>&fields[Browser]=<?php echo $Browser;?>" target="_blank">Please fill out the form</a>
</noscript>

<div class="podio-webform-container">
  The simplest way to <a href="https://podio.com" class="podio-webform-inner" rel="nofollow">manage projects</a> out there
</div>
<!-- END Podio web form -->
```

Unfortunately this won't work. Does anyone have any experience of this? Some of the information is to pre-populate the form, and others are hidden data like the viewer's IP address and Country plus the Current URL.

I have looked in the Podio support pages, but there's no mention of how to pass variable via the Javascript form.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Podio currently does not support a convenient mechanism for supplying defaults for *embedded* webforms. Only the Podio-hosted webforms support that feature today. I've asked around with my colleagues, and we'll enter this feature request into our backlog for evaluation.

Meanwhile, if you still need auto-populated defaults while hosting your own embedded version, you could use JavaScript to inject values into the HTML form fields *after* they the iframe has loaded (this happens when the `_podioWebForm.render("xxxxxx")` call completes).